# Automatic Do Not Disturb for Calendar events on Samsung

Tags: samsung, android-10

Does anyone know of any free apps that can control the Do Not Disturb based on Calendar events? I know this is built into Android OS10, but Samsung has removed that from their phones. I know of one app that should work but it does a lot of things I do not need and costs money for what was originally built in but removed by a second party.

Comment: You can try IFTTT, Automate, Macrodroid app and automate that. look given examples and try to create automation script for those calendar events.

Answer (score 0):

This one works great on modern Android devices:

Check out "Silent During Meetings"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.ysharon.quietinmeeting

I made one with some nice settings in Tasker back in 2013, but that one doesn't work anymore on modern Android systems. I imagine Tasker would still work fine nowadays.

Comment: Frustrating that Samsung removed that from their phones. I used the built in Android version for ages.